# Clojure form - Submit when press enter

Tags: clojure, hiccup

I have a search-form that searches some text for me. When I type in the input box I have to manually press a button for it to search. Is there a way for me to hit `enter` on the keyboard and have that search, as well as the button?

```
(defn search-form
  []
  [:div
   [:p "What are you searching for? "
    [:input
     {:type :text
      :name :search
      :on-change #(swap! fields assoc :search (-> % .-target .-value))
      :value (:search @fields)}]]
   [:input
    {:type :submit
     :value :Search
     :on-click #(do
                 (search-function (:search @fields)))}]
   [@search-results]])
```

This is the code I currently have. As you can see, to call the `search-function` I have to click on the button. I would like to be able to press `enter` and also have the ability to press the button and both will call `search-function`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: i guess if you put your outer div into the `:form` tag, you will be able to listen to its `onSubmit` event, and do whatever you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like `:on-key-down` for the event, and I think you are looking for the number `13`. Ran across it when I was reading the source code for [reagent-forms](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent-forms/blob/master/src/reagent_forms/core.cljs#L261) though I am not sure where the documentation would be.

Closest documentation that I could find is [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html), though `React` tests for the `Enter` key explicitly [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/e3131c1d55d6695c2f0966379535f88b813f912b/src/renderers/dom/shared/utils/__tests__/getEventKey-test.js#L35).